# Changing the last element of a string if it is an 'e'

Tags: python, string

I am creating a program that converts a normal English word into a form of pig-latin. I need to be able to determine if the string ends (last character) in an 'e', and if it does, replace it with ë.

I can't seem to be able to get it to work using my function. For example, the code should output the word 'happy" as "appyhë" by the end of this condition.

```
# User Input: Ask user for a word

WordToBeTranslated = input("Please enter a word in English: ")
WordToBeTranslatedLower = WordToBeTranslated.lower()

# Condition #1: Moving the First Letter to the end

elvish = WordToBeTranslatedLower[1:] + WordToBeTranslatedLower[0]
print(elvish)

# Condition #2 + #3: Appending a Vowel / Appending 'en' to the end of a word

vowel = ['a', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
import random
randomVowel = random.choice(vowel)
list = []
list.append(WordToBeTranslated)
if len(WordToBeTranslated) > 4:
    elvish += randomVowel

else:
    elvish = elvish + 'en'

# Condition #4: change all k's to c's

elvish = elvish.replace('k', 'c')
print(elvish)

# Condition #5: Replace 'e' at end of the word with ë

if elvish[-1] == 'e':
    elvish = elvish[-1].replace('e', 'ë')
else:
    elvish = elvish
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Why do you think that, after condition 2, there is **always** an `e` appended?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
your_string.endswith("e")
```

You can also use a RegEx to substitute the "e" with "ë".

```
import re

your_string = re.sub(r"e$", "ë")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
elvish = elvish[-1].replace('e', 'ë')
```

doesn't at all do what you want. It reassigns `elvish` with *just* the last letter, replacing the e if necessary.

Now, you know inside this if block that the last letter is an e, so you always need to replace it. What you want to do then is to take the original string minus the last letter, and append `ë`. So:

```
elvish = elvish[:-1] + 'ë'
```

Also, you don't need an else block; yours does nothing, you can just remove it.